# dar formato array a un string ruby

Tags: array, string, ruby, rubygems, retorno

En ruby tengo este string

```
line ="[ERROR]"
```

quiero tomarlo como array ejemplo

```
return line[0] 
# ERROR
```

pero al hacer me retorna

```
  return line[0] 
    # [
```

Como hago para pasar ese string que tiene dentro las llaves a array

Comment: Sería mejor generar el array desde la fuente; ¿tienes control alguno sobre la línea `line = "[ERROR]"`? De lo contrario tendrás que hacer la conversión manualmente (e.g. `[line.delete("[]")]`)

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución podría ser esta:

**gsub** con **\W** reemplaza los no-dígitos en        strings vacios(en este caso quita los corchetes y deja la palabra ERROR

**split** convierte el string en un array

```
line = "[ERROR]".gsub(/\W/, '').split(',')
# ["ERROR"]
return line[0]
# "ERROR"
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente el funcionamiento del código: lee [answer].